# Corollary to Yoneda Lemma

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I'm working from Rotman's Homological Algebra text. There's just one detail of the Corollary that I don't follow.

### 1. Yoneda Lemma

> **Theorem 1.17 (Yoneda Lemma).** *Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category, let $A \in \text{obj}(\mathcal{C})$, and let $G : \mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Sets}$ be a covariant functor. Then there is a bijection*
>
> $$y : \text{Nat}(\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,\square), G) \to G(A)$$
>
> *given by $y : \tau \mapsto \tau_A(1_A).$*

### 2. Corollary

> **Corollary 1.18.** *Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and let $A, B \in \text{obj}(\mathcal{C})$.*
>
> (i) *If $\tau : \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,\square) \to \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,\square)$ is a natural transformation, then for all $C \in \text{obj}(\mathcal{C})$, we have $\tau_C = \psi^*$ where $\psi = \tau_A(1_A) : B \to A$ and $\psi^*$ is the induced map $\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,C) \to \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,C)$ given by $\varphi \mapsto \varphi \psi$. Moreover, the morphism $\psi$ is unique: if $\tau_C = \theta^*$, then $\theta = \psi.$*

> *Proof.*
>
> (i) If we denote $\tau_A(1_A) \in \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,A)$ by $\psi$, then the Yoneda Lemma says, for all $C \in \text{obj}(\mathcal{C})$ and all $\varphi \in \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,C)$, that $\tau_C(\varphi) = \varphi_*(\psi)$. But $\varphi_*(\psi) = \varphi \psi = \psi^*(\varphi)$. The uniqueness assertion follows from injectivity of the Yoneda function $y$

### 3. Question

I don't see why the uniqueness of $\psi$ follows from the injectivity of $y$. We have $\psi^* = \tau_C = \theta^*$. In other words, for all $\phi \in \text{Hom}(A,C)$, $\phi \psi = \phi \theta$.

We can also say that $\theta^* = y(\tau)^*$. If we knew that $\text{Hom}(A,C)$ contained an injective morphism, the result would certainly follow. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The yoneda embedding $y$ eats an object $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and spits out a functor $y(C) = \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(C, \square) : \mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$. Now the yoneda lemma tells us that for any other functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Sets}$ we have a bijection

$$
\text{Nat}(y(C), F) \cong F(C)
$$

(remember that $\text{Nat}(y(C),F)$ is the set of natural transformations, and $F(C)$ is the set $F$ assigns to the object $C$).

Now let's look at $\text{Nat}(\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,\square), \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,\square))$, which we can write as $\text{Nat}(y(A), \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,\square))$. The yoneda lemma says that this set of natural transformations is in bijection with $\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,\square)(A) = \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,A)$. In fact, it tells us the bijection!

To each $\tau \in \text{Nat}(\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,\square), \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,\square))$, we assign the arrow $\psi = \tau_A(1_A) \in \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,A)$.

Conversely, to each $\psi \in \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,A)$ we assign the natural transformation $\tau = \psi^* \in \text{Nat}(\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,\square), \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,\square))$.

Let's mainly pay attention to the map $\psi \mapsto \psi^*$. What does it mean that this map is a bijection? Surjectivity tells us that *every* natural transformation $\tau$ is $\psi^*$ for some $\psi$. Injectivity says exactly that the $\psi$ associated with some $\tau$ is unique! Indeed, if $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are different arrows in $\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,A)$, they must get sent to different natural transformations $\tau_1 = \psi_1^*$ and $\tau_2 = \psi_2^*$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand but just 2 clarifications. I believe you're referring to the Yoneda embedding $Y$ which is a functor. I'm just about to review this corollary but haven't yet.

Comment: Second, we don't have $\tau = \psi^*$ but instead $\tau_C = \psi^*$. But then $\psi \mapsto \tau \mapsto \tau_C$ is a composition of injective functions, so that $\psi$ must be unique. $\tau \mapsto \tau_C$ must be injective, otherwise the hom sets would not be disjoint (a requirement of categories). Did I get this all right?